# Find cells on one sheet and copy the rows to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, autofilter

I have a sheet called Backlog containing rows and columns of data.  I need code that will search row by row in the 2nd to last column looking for #N/A.  When it finds #N/A it needs to check the last column if it contains a C or not.  If it contains a C then the whole row should be appended to a sheet called Logoff.  If the last column does not contain a C then the whole row should be appended to a sheet called Denied.  The row should be deleted from the original Backlog sheet once moved to either Logoff or Denied.  The code I have below is not working.  After the first For Statement it goes to End Sub, but there is not any compiling errors.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim IMBacklogSh As Worksheet
    Set IMBacklogSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backlog")
    Dim logoffSh As Worksheet
    Set logoffSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Claims Logged off")
    Dim deniedsh As Worksheet
    Set deniedsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Claims Denied")

    IMBacklogSh.Select
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 13).Value = "#N/A" Then
            If Cells(i, 14).Value = "C" Then
            IMBacklogSh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=logoffSh.Range("A" & logoffsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            Else
            IMBacklogSh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=deniedsh.Range("A" & deniedsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The linked duplicate shows you how to find the errors in a column. Copying to another worksheet is a simple matter. Come back and edit your question to include your own effort if you run into trouble figuring out how to copy a row.

Comment: I added my code.  I can't figure out why it doesn't work after the For statement.  When I debug it skips to the End immediately after the For i = 3 statement and doesn't appear to evaluate any of the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it as `If Cells(i, 13).Text = "#N/A" Then` . `#N/A` is an error code, not a value; however, the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) can be examined or the [IsError function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx) could be used to examine the cell's contents for any error.

```
    If Cells(i, 13).Text = "#N/A" Then
    'Alternate with IsError
    'If IsError(Cells(i, 13)) Then
        If Cells(i, 14).Value = "C" Then
            IMBacklogSh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=logoffSh.Range("A" & logoffsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        Else
            IMBacklogSh.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=deniedsh.Range("A" & deniedsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    End If
```

However, individual cell examination is not necessary and time consuming. The [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) can be used to isolate `#N/A` with `C` and `#N/A` with `<>C`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim IMBacklogSh As Worksheet, logoffSh As Worksheet, deniedsh As Worksheet

    Set IMBacklogSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backlog")
    Set logoffSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Claims Logged off")
    Set deniedsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Claims Denied")

    With IMBacklogSh
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=13, Criteria1:="#N/A"
            .AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:="C"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Copy Destination:= _
                        logoffSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    'optionally delete the originals
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
            .AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:="<>C"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Copy Destination:= _
                        deniedsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    'optionally delete the originals
                    .EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped.  The AutoFilter code worked perfectly.